# getmerge command in hadoop datacopy

Tags: hadoop

My aim is to read all the files that starts with  "trans" in a directory  and convert them into a single file and load  that single file into HDFS location

my source directory is /user/cloudera/inputfiles/

Assume that inside that above directory , there are lot of file , but i need all the files that start with "trans"

my destination directory is /user/cloudera/transfiles/

So i tried this command below

```
hadoop dfs - getmerge /user/cloudera/inputfiles/trans* /user/cloudera/transfiles/records.txt
```

but the above command is not working .

If i try the below command then it works

```
hadoop dfs - getmerge /user/cloudera/inputfiles   /user/cloudera/transfiles/records.txt
```

Any suggestion on how do i merge some files from a hdfs location and store that merged single file in another hdfs location

Comment: Is getmerge command only for all files inside a directory?

Answer (score 5):

Below is the usage of getmerge command:

```
Usage: hdfs dfs -getmerge <src> <localdst> [addnl]

Takes a source directory and a destination file as input and 
concatenates files in src into the destination local file. 
Optionally addnl can be set to enable adding a newline character at the
end of each file.
```

It expects directory as first parameter.

you can try cat command like this:

```
hadoop dfs -cat /user/cloudera/inputfiles/trans* > /<local_fs_dir>/records.txt
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /<local_fs_dir>/records.txt /user/cloudera/transfiles/records.txt
```

Comment: Ok that means getmerge is only for all files inside a directory.Am i right?

Comment: Yes, and the destination will be your local file system.

Comment: hadoop dfs -cat /user/cloudera/inputfiles/trans* > /<local_fs_dir>/records.txt. I am asking that last line of trans1.txt and 1st line of trans2.txt will get displayed on a single line.so how do I fix that . I  don't want two content of two lines in a single line

Comment: It's because you don't have a new line character at the end of file. Just add that to source files while creating it.